# How to configure Elasticsearch plugin in grails 3.3.2

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, grails

I try to make a simple search engine using grails, mongodb and elasticsearch. I create new project in grails, use mongodb plugin and set server url, database name in the environment. It works fine.

But after adding elasticsearch plugin, when i run, it shows the following error

***FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.

> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   | Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)***

Would you please give me details information about how to configure Elasticsearch in grails. Thank you.

Comment: "Use --stacktrace to see the full trace"

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to add an additional dependency in your Gradle file.

```
  compile 'org.elasticsearch.plugin:mapper-attachments:2.3.3'
```

But of course, do check the stacktraces to confirm your errors.